# asm/errno.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, gcc

While building gcc, I get this error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/bits/errno.h:25,
             from /usr/include/errno.h:36,
             from ../.././gcc/tsystem.h:96,
             from ../.././gcc/crtstuff.c:68:
/usr/include/linux/errno.h:4:23: error: asm/errno.h: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [crtbegin.o] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/gcc-4.1.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc'
```

I am building gcc 4.1 from source. I think I have to install `build-essential`. However installing that package in ubuntu 12.04 will automatically download and install gcc 4.6 and I don't want that.

Is there any other way?

Comment: same problem when i cross compile for s390 on x86
sles1032bit
In file included from /var/tmp/toolchain/experiment_2/sysroot.s390x/usr/include/errno.h:35:0,
                 from /var/tmp/toolchain/experiment_2/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/../gcc/tsystem.h:93,
                 from /var/tmp/toolchain/experiment_2/gcc-4.8.5/libgcc/libgcc2.c:27:
/var/tmp/toolchain/experiment_2/sysroot.s390x/usr/include/bits/errno.h:24:26: fatal error: linux/errno.h: No such file or directory
 # include <linux/errno.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
make[4]: *** [_negdi2.o] Error 1

Answer (score 53):

I think the package you want is `linux-libc-dev` . I encountered this when building 32-on-64; so I needed `linux-libc-dev:i386` .

Comment: With both installed on Ubuntu 15.10, `diff -ur /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/ /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/asm/` shows no differences.  Some other files outside those directories are provided by both packages, but apparently this is ok, and you only have multiple copies of those 62 files totalling ~340k.  `dpkg -L linux-libc-dev | diff -ur - <(dpkg -L linux-libc-dev:i386)` shows that both packages provide the same files outside the arch-specific include directory.

Comment: So if you're going to symlink instead of keeping the package manager happy by installing `linux-libc-dev:i386` on a 64bit system, use `ln -s x86_64-linux-gnu /usr/include/i386-linux-gnu` to make a relative symlink.

Comment: Thanks! I hit this when building LLVM's compiler-rt. I was missing `linux-libc-dev:i386`.

Answer (score 44):

This worked for me:

```
ln -s /usr/include/asm-generic /usr/include/asm
```

Comment: Indeed, it looks similar to what you would get if you do `apt-get install gcc-multilib` (`apt-file search /usr/include/asm` shows this package) and on my system, having that installed, `/usr/include/asm` is a symbolic link. Not sure whether this package depends on `build-essential` or not though.

Comment: Creating symlinks like this in the rootfs is not a good idea as these files are "owned" by apt/dpkg. By messing with them like this, you may run into issues in the future.

Answer (score 27):

This worked for me:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/include/asm-generic /usr/include/asm
```

The reason being that what GCC expects to be called `/usr/include/asm` is renamed to `/usr/include/asm-generic` in some distros.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess nobody cares enough to fix it.  Do they not run their own installers across distros?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm this works for me running n0000bunt00.

Comment: Creating symlinks like this in the rootfs is not a good idea as these files are "owned" by apt/dpkg. By messing with them like this, you may run into issues in the future.

Answer (score 12):

This solved it for me on Debian 10, even though I was compiling with an LLVM-based compiler:

```
sudo apt install gcc-multilib
```

Comment: This is the proper solution, not symlinking system files which may result in conflicts in the future

Comment: This solution is which finally helped me!

Comment: this is the appropriate way of solving this issue

Answer (score 6):

This fixed it for me.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev:i386
```

Comment: E: Unable to locate package linux-libc-dev:386

Answer (score 3):

`/usr/include/asm/errno.h` is part of the linux headers.  I can't speak directly to Ubuntu 12.04, but in general you can download the linux sources as a package for your distro and it shouldn't require you to download/install gcc.  Failing that, you can manually download the linux headers for the version of your kernel (`uname -a`) and use an include directive to CFLAGS to specify the directory to look for those.

Edit: `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic` may work for you.

Comment: my kernel is 3.2.0-24-generic. `apt-get install linux-headers-3.2.0-2` shows it is installed. `apt-get install linux-headers-generic` will download linux-headers-3.2.0-37 which is wrong

Comment: I'd try a few things.  One is `find /usr/include -name errno.h` to see if it's hiding in version-specific directory.  The other is look in `/usr/src/` to see if you have the kernel source downloaded; if not, see if there's a package to download it (like linux-sources maybe?).  When found, point to it with CFLAGS `-I/path/to/src/include`.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing part of the development packages. I don't know Ubuntu, but you should be able to ask it's package management system to install the package containing `/usr/include/asm/errno.h`.

*Do not* copy some file with a similar name from somewhere on your system (or, even worse, from somewhere else). Missing files might mean that some package is damaged; again, ask your package manager to check everything and (re)install missing/broken pieces.

Unless you are running some LTS release, upgrade. Your Ubuntu is some 2 years old, i.e., ancient.

While we are at this, why on this beautiful planet are you building such an ancient compiler? Current GCC is just released 4.9.0, anything before 4.7 is ancient history, not longer supported.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 16.04 x86_64 you could try this:

```sh
ln -s /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm /usr/include/asm
```

This works on my server.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use errno.h that is in the asm file, simply go to /usr/(ctrl + l, type /usr/) and then search for errno.h and errno-base.h. Once you did find them, copy the code in these two files, and place them in your include folder. And be careful, in "errno.h" the file includes "errno-base.h" as:

```
#include <asm-generic/errno-base.h>
```

Either create a directory with the same name above or change the code above to something different which is suitable for you to use.

Answer (score 0):

This solved for me on Ubuntu 22.04

```
sudo apt-get install linux-libc-dev
```

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue while compiling Asterisk 1.8.24.0 and solved it with:

```
mkdir /usr/include/asm-generic
cp /usr/include/asm/errno-base.h /usr/include/asm-generic/
```

Don't know if it is the "right way" but i've read the comments above and that gave me the idea... and it worked :)

Answer (score -1):

If you can find:

`usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h`

by executing:

`find /usr/include -name errno.h`

then try to execute:

`cp --archive /usr/include/asm-generic /usr/include/asm`

It may fix that problem.